# How to create "point on surface" equivalent in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

Sometimes, a centroid falls outside of a polygon in Earth Engine, such as in this example:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5830819bae20d6d25ec7fe66adb4f66f

To overcome this issue, QGIS has a "Point on Surface" algorithm ( https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools.html#point-on-surface ) that will ensure that the centroid-like object actually falls within the bounds of the polygon.

Does anyone know how to accomplish the same in Earth Engine and use this point as the centroid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's a parameter or function as such which can allow you to force the centroid into the polygon. However, you could work around it by calculating the shortest distance between your centroid and your polygon, and then moving the point by that distance so it lies on the edge of the polygon, like this:

```
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[-122.092, 37.424],
    [-122.086, 37.418],
    [-122.079, 37.425],
    [-122.086, 37.4187]]]);

  // Get centroid
var polygonCentroid = polygon.centroid(ee.ErrorMargin(1));
  // Measure shortest distance to polygon
var distance = polygonCentroid.distance({right:polygon,maxError:ee.ErrorMargin(1)});
  // Create buffer area
var polygonCentroidBuffer = polygonCentroid.buffer({
  distance: distance.add(1), // One is added to force the buffer to intersect with the shape
  maxError: ee.ErrorMargin(1)
});
  // Move centroid
var intersection = polygonCentroidBuffer.intersection(polygon,ee.ErrorMargin(1)) //Outputs a polygon
  .centroid(ee.ErrorMargin(1)); //Get centroid of intersecting polygon
  // Add to map
Map.centerObject(polygon);
Map.addLayer(polygon,
  {'color': 'black'},
  'Geometry [black]: polygon');
Map.addLayer(polygonCentroid,
  {'color': 'red'},
  'Result [red]: polygon.centroid');
Map.addLayer(polygonCentroidBuffer,
  {'color': 'blue'},
  'Buffer around centroid');
Map.addLayer(intersection,
  {'color': 'green'},
  'Moved centroid');
```

It of course depends on what "rule" you want to use to force your point inside of the polygon, though anything other than "shortest distance" and things might get a little more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for the effective work-around!